# Antlr4 token recognition error and extraneous input

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to create SQL interpreter for my project. I ran into these errors when I run my program.

```
line 2:28 token recognition error at: ''a'
line 2:33 token recognition error at: '','
line 2:30 extraneous input 'nna' expecting Value
```

This is my test sql query:

```
INSERT INTO teacher VALUES ('Anna', 21);
```

And the partial of my grammar is:

```
insert: INSERT INTO ValidName VALUES '(' Value (',' Value)* ')' ';' ;
Value: Number | String;
ValidName: [a-z][a-z0-9_]*;
Number: [0-9]+;
String: '\''[^']+'\'';
```

I try to print out ctx.children and got this:

```
[INSERT, INTO, teacher, VALUES, (, nna, 21, ), ;]
```

Would anyone please help me where did I do wrong?

Comment: Unless this is for a school project, I’d not write such a thing from scratch. Either find a grammar or parser from Github, or look for one on https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thing should help:

1 - `Value` should probably be a parser rule rather than a Lexer rule:

```
value: Number | String;
```

(and change the `Values`s in your rules to `value`s

2 - For your `STRING` rule, it's a bit simpler to use the non-greedy operator to pick up everything until you match the next character:

```
STRING: '\'' .*? '\'';
```